# Insert into multiple tables in single transaction with FK relationship

Tags: asp.net, sql

I created SP for handle transaction when insert multiple table but getting exception below

My SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Insert_BankData]
@xmlBankItems   XML ,
@xmlAccDetails XML,
@xmlPosition XML
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TranStarted   bit
SET @TranStarted = 0

    IF( @@TRANCOUNT = 0 )
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            SET @TranStarted = 1
        END
    ELSE
        SET @TranStarted = 0

    INSERT INTO BankItem([BankItemId],[PortfolioId],[ItemIdentifier],[ItemDisplayName])
    SELECT  r.value('BankItemId[1]','uniqueidentifier'),r.value('PortfolioId[1]','uniqueidentifier'),
            r.value('ItemIdentifier[1]','bigint'),r.value('ItemDisplayName[1]','varchar(150)')
    FROM @xmlBankItems.nodes('bankItem') t(r)


    INSERT INTO BankAccountDetails (BankAccountId,BankItemId, AccountName,AccountDescription)
                    SELECT ac.value('BankAccountId[1]','uniqueidentifier'),ac.value('BankItemId[1]','uniqueidentifier'),
                            ac.value('AccountName[1]','varchar(150)'),ac.value('AccountDescription[1]','varchar(50)')
                    FROM @xmlAccDetails.nodes('accDetail') t(ac) 

    INSERT INTO Positions(PositionId,BankItemId,AccountCode,Ticker)
                    SELECT  p.value('PositionId[1]','uniqueidentifier'),p.value('BankItemId[1]','uniqueidentifier'),
                            p.value('AccountCode[1]','bigint'),p.value('Ticker[1]','varchar(50)')
                    FROM @xmlPosition.nodes('position') t(p) 

    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
        GOTO Cleanup

     IF( @TranStarted = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SET @TranStarted = 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END

    Cleanup:
        IF( @TranStarted = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SET @TranStarted = 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
END
```

-----------------Exception----------------

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BankAccountItems'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BankItem'. The duplicate key value is (4bb6e35b-900b-4d0c-890e-48944abfe976).
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BankData_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BankAccountDetails'. The duplicate key value is (952d89d6-bd3b-4408-b00d-644ab15ee9c0).
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Positions'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Positions'. The duplicate key value is (4d030b2e-fbf3-40b7-9ae4-ab0aeb2138f0).
The statement has been terminated.
The statement has been terminated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: are your column `BankItemId`, `BankAccountId`, `PositionId` identity in database?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is duplicate data already exists in the table(s) mentioned in the error. The error gives the key values that are in violation. Query your tables for those keys -- if they exist, the insert(s) will fail, and transactions won't help you with that.

Comment: The child tables have multiple rows, this proc when i am executing from SQL its self its working fine but when calling it from application its throwing exception(both end i m using same same data)